# Hosting multiple site with single CloudFront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I want to configure two s3 bucket for two site like bucket A and bucket B for A.com and B.com respectively.

i was went through following step.

1) I created on CloudFront distribution.
2) created two origin for different bucket.
3) both have public accessible policy.
4) for first origin with A bucket have default cash behaviour.
5) for second origin  with B bucket have cash behaviour with path patter 
    /B

Bucket A with hghd/clodfront.net is accessible here.

Bucket B with hghd/clodfront.net/B fire HTML error NO such key found.

here where i am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to host two sites on a single CloudFront distribution?

Comment: I am new in AWS for that i am not that much expert. please let me know for my scenario, is it best practice? I have two environment site test and production. I deployed both sites on different s3 buckets and trying to host both sites via single clodfront.

Answer (score 0):

FIY: i resolve this with convert both bucket to a sub directories of one single bucket and configure clodfront's CacheBehavior.